# inittab file had duplicate ID field - can't ctrl-c out of it

Tags: linux, inittab

I have a TS-7200 sbc card from Technologic Systems running linux and I am trying to modify the inittab file so it logs in as root and automatically runs my application. I obviously did something wrong in the inittab file because now when I reboot it I get:

```
INIT: version 2.85-ts1.00 booting
INIT: /etc/inittab[72]: duplicate ID field "ca"
INIT: cannot execute "/etc/init.d/rcS"
INIT: Entering runlevel: 3
INIT: cannot execute "/etc/init.d/rc"
INIT: Id "gel" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel
```

Then I keep getting the last 2 lines every 5 minutes and can't ctrl-c out of it. (or ctrl-d).

I can't think of anything other than to reflash the card. (which I don't know how to do yet).

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK I'll head over there...